# RichEdit paint background

Tags: vcl, win32gui, richedit, trichedit, c++builder-xe3

I know how to change the background on a single row in a `TRichEdit` control. But because this is applied to the selected text only, I can't set the background color of the whole line (client left to client right), only to the text part.

I tried to use the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message, but it doesn't work because a RichEdit control is painting the background in its `WM_PAINT` handler.

I also tried to set the brush to `bsClear` before calling the `WM_PAINT` handler, but it didn't work either.

Is it possible at all to have a custom drawn background?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to do so by using the [EM_SETBKGNDCOLOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

Comment: No, this sets the whole control's background. I want to set the background of a single line from client left to client right.